# Add '-' between each character in a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string

How to do that? I am willing to add the character `-` after every character in a certain string.
For a specific case assume I have a string declared in the size of 100 but filled with only 3 letters (entered by the user - so the value of the character `str[3]` is NULL (`\0`)).

```
for(i = strlen(str) ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    str[i*2] = str[i];
}
for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(str) ; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        str[i] = '-';
    }
}
```

but it's not working, help anyone?

Comment: Not working? What happens? Doesn't print at all, doesn't print correct sequence?

Comment: E.g. The string is ASD - the output is A-S - it's not using the memory defined to the string. Can't I move or erase somehow the character "NULL"?

Comment: Instead of doing `++` and an even/odd check, you could just `i+=2`.

Comment: Think about this: why would `strlen(str)` return a different value in the second loop? Your answer is there.

Comment: The problem is that the second for loop is limited by `strlen(str)`, instead of `strlen(str)*2`.

Comment: i = strlen(str); and str[i*2];  shouldn't this return index out of boud???

Comment: @sora0419 No, he said the array is 100 long.

Comment: @sora0419: C doesn't range check, so it will never return any such thing. Also, if the buffer is large enough, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char str[100];
   int len = 0;
   int i = 0;
   strcpy(str, "abcd");

   len = strlen(str);
   // len = 4

   // Expected output: "a-b-c-d"
   // str[7] = '\0';
   // str[6] = 'd';
   for(i = len-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
   {
      str[i*2+1] = '-';
      str[i*2] = str[i];
   }
   str[len*2-1] = '\0';

   printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to handle the terminating zero of the string in the first loop. After it, the original terminating zero is still in place:

```
A S D \0
A S S \0 D x \0
```

So at the beginning of the second loop `strlen(str)` is still 3.

When the second loop gets to the first `\0` to replace it with `-`, the loop terminates instead, due to the condition in the `for` statement.

You'd better insert the hyphens straight away in the first loop.

```
for (i = strlen(str); i > 0; i--) {
    str[i*2] = str[i];
    str[i*2-1] = '-';
}
```

Note, the loop above goes down to 1 only, as you can leave the `A` in place anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a secondary string to store your changed results.

```
char str[100] = "ASD";
char changed[100*2 - 1] = "";
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(str); i++, j+=2)
{
    changed[j] = str[i];
    if (i < strlen(str)-1)
    {
        changed[j + 1] = '-';
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(changed); i++)
{
    printf("%c", changed[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use only first for loop and make this changes to your for loop

```
for(i = strlen(str)-1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
{
   str[i*2] = str[i];
   str[i*2-1] = '-';
}
```